# Where clause when table is not null and returns a list of users and users that belong to same state

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to return values of customers that may be filtered if a custom list is set in the DB.

If the custom list is uploaded I want to write a query to return all customers in that list as well as any customers that belong to that state. Otherwise just return an unfiltered list if no list has been set.

This is what I wrote hoping that would accomplish my goal, but it is failing to filter if the list was uploaded and returns the same data if commented out :

```
SELECT U.userId
      ,U.State 
       FROM UsersAndStates U
       LEFT JOIN @CustomUsersAndState C -- variable table where custom list is stored for this query
       on U.userId= C.userId
WHERE U.userId LIKE CASE WHEN C.userId IS NOT NULL
                         THEN '%' + C.userId + '%'
                         WHEN C.userId IS NULL
                         THEN '%' + U.userId + '%'
                         WHEN C.State = U.State 
                         THEN '%' + U.userId + '%
                         END
```

Thank you for reading.

edit:fixed alias mistake

Comment: From where `S.userId ` come from?

Comment: sorry, that was a formatting mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic simplifies to:

```
SELECT U.userId, U.State 
FROM UsersAndStates U LEFT JOIN
     @CustomUsersAndState C -- variable table where custom list is stored for this query
     ON U.userId= C.userId
WHERE (C.UserId IS NOT NULL AND U.userId LIKE '%' + C.userId + '%') OR
      C.userId IS NULL
```

You might ask:  "What happened to the state condition?"  Well, `c.userId` is either `NULL` or not `NULL`, so the third condition in the `CASE` is never executed.

Generally, boolean expressions are considered easier to follow than `CASE` statements in a `WHERE` clause.  At the very least, they are easier for the optimizer to handle.

If I understand you conditions correctly, you would seem to want:

```
SELECT U.userId, U.State 
FROM UsersAndStates U LEFT JOIN
     @CustomUsersAndState C -- variable table where custom list is stored for this query
     ON U.userId = C.userId
WHERE (C.UserId IS NOT NULL AND
       (U.userId LIKE '%' + C.userId + '%' OR
        U.state = C.state
       )
      ) OR
      C.userId IS NULL
```

I am unclear why you are using `LIKE` for the `userId`, when `=` would seem to suffice:

```
WHERE (C.UserId IS NOT NULL AND (U.userId = C.userId OR U.state = C.state)
      ) OR
      C.userId IS NULL
```

EDIT:

I think the logic you really want is:

```
SELECT U.userId, U.State 
FROM UsersAndStates U 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @CustomUsersAndState C) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM @CustomUsersAndState C
              WHERE U.userId LIKE C.userId OR U.state = C.state
             );
```

Comment: I was just adding a comment to the original question about using `LIKE` instead of `=` for the `userId` compare when I saw you added that your answer. There are major performance implications with the leading wildcard in the search pattern.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The `LIKE` was just my final attempt to return something. Unfortunately your suggestion is returning all other users that don't belong to that state. The first part of the clause before the `OR` returns the list filtered to the users.

Comment: @WSilhavy . . . I don't understand the comment.  If `c.UserId` is `NULL`, then the second table is empty.  Hence, all users are returned.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant the first part of the clause was only returning users that were on the upload, but not users that also belong to that state that aren't part of the upload. Using the entire statement will just return  an unfiltered results even if there are records in the 2nd table

Comment: @WSilhavy . . . See my edit.  You don't want a `JOIN`.

Comment: that works perfectly. Thanks for helping me stumble through it.